# Matrix, and array

Tags: php

I have a problem I can not solve this task at all.
can you help me.

We have a multivariate array that describes something like an Excel table or matrix, ect.
the first index represents the row and the second column. The rows can have a
different number of elements (columns). Count the amounts in the columns and select the highest.

```
$a = [[1, 3, 4], [2, 5], [2 => 3, 5 => 8], [1, 1, 5 => 1]];
```

Comment: Your question is pretty unclear. Can you show us the expected result? You should also include your attempts and the result from that. We're glad to help you with your code, but we won't write it all for you.

Comment: I don't see a question or even  understand what the problem is.

Comment: I guess this wasn't that important for the OP since we haven't gotten any response for 45 minutes...

Comment: Sorry, for this mess.

I'm still learning, my questions are not well formulated.

the answer should be.

array (size=6)
  0 => int 4
  1 => int 9
  2 => int 7
  3 => int 0
  4 => int 0
  5 => int 9

Comment: How to count?
Count the amounts in the columns and select the highest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some code that does what you asked:

```
$a = [[1, 3, 4], [2, 5], [2 => 3, 5 => 8], [1, 1, 5 => 1]];

$columnValues = [];
$lastColumn = 0;
foreach($a as $row){
    foreach($row as $column => $value){
        if($column > $lastColumn)
            $lastColumn = $column;

        if(isset($columnValues[$column]))
            $columnValues[$column] += $value;
        else 
            $columnValues[$column] = $value;
    }
}

//if you want to include empty columns too:
for($column = 0; $column <= $lastColumn; $column++){
    if(!isset($columnValues[$column]))
        $columnValues[$column] = 0;
}

//sorting the column values by index:
ksort($columnValues);

$highestValue =  max($columnValues);
$highestValueColumns = array_keys($array, max($array)); //contains all columns that have the same highest value. If there's only one column with the highest value, you can access it with $highestValueColumns[0];
```